# How to Properly Import .ovf and .vmdk from VMware into VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware

The .ovf and .vmdk don't seem to work with VirtualBox, giving me an error saying that the .vmdk has not been created yet, even when I point the program to the file in the .ovf import screen. It doesn't even start to import before it gives me the error.

`Storage for the medium 'C:\Users\schalcay000\Desktop\RSS-VM-32BITS-disk1.vmdk' is not created.`

It gives me this error code below it.

`VBOX_E_INVALID_OBJECT_STATE (0x80BB0007)`

Whenever I try to import the .ovf with all default settings, excluding the 'import hard drives as VDI', since the hard drive is in .vmdk format, it starts to import, then it stops at 12% and gives me the same error, but saying the hard disk file is not in the VM directory.

`Storage for the medium 'C:\Users\schalcay000\VirtualBox VMs\vm\RSS-VM-32BITS-disk1.vmdk' is not created.`

When I put the file in that folder, it gives me the same error, but adding a (1) after disk1. It's like it's avoiding the file. Please help!

Here's the .ovf file if you would like to examine it:

````
<!--Generated by VMware ovftool 4.0.0 (build-2301625), UTC time: 2016-02-05T16:06:59.429481Z-->
<Envelope vmw:buildId="build-2301625" xmlns="http://schemas.dmtf.org/ovf/envelope/1" xmlns:cim="http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wscim/1/common" xmlns:ovf="http://schemas.dmtf.org/ovf/envelope/1" xmlns:rasd="http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wscim/1/cim-schema/2/CIM_ResourceAllocationSettingData" xmlns:vmw="http://www.vmware.com/schema/ovf" xmlns:vssd="http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wscim/1/cim-schema/2/CIM_VirtualSystemSettingData" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <References>
    <File ovf:href="RSS-VM-32BITS-disk1.vmdk" ovf:id="file1" ovf:size="2999185408"/>
  </References>
  <DiskSection>
    <Info>Virtual disk information</Info>
    <Disk ovf:capacity="40" ovf:capacityAllocationUnits="byte * 2^30" ovf:diskId="vmdisk1" ovf:fileRef="file1" ovf:format="http://www.vmware.com/interfaces/specifications/vmdk.html#streamOptimized" ovf:populatedSize="7630422016"/>
  </DiskSection>
  <NetworkSection>
    <Info>The list of logical networks</Info>
    <Network ovf:name="bridged">
      <Description>The bridged network</Description>
    </Network>
  </NetworkSection>
  <VirtualSystem ovf:id="vm">
    <Info>A virtual machine</Info>
    <Name>RSS-VM-32BITS</Name>
    <OperatingSystemSection ovf:id="93" vmw:osType="ubuntuGuest">
      <Info>The kind of installed guest operating system</Info>
    </OperatingSystemSection>
    <VirtualHardwareSection>
      <Info>Virtual hardware requirements</Info>
      <System>
        <vssd:Caption>Virtual Hardware Family</vssd:Caption>
        <vssd:InstanceID>0</vssd:InstanceID>
        <vssd:VirtualSystemIdentifier>RSS-VM-32BITS</vssd:VirtualSystemIdentifier>
        <vssd:VirtualSystemType>vmx-10</vssd:VirtualSystemType>
      </System>
      <Item>
        <rasd:AllocationUnits>hertz * 10^6</rasd:AllocationUnits>
        <rasd:Description>Number of Virtual CPUs</rasd:Description>
        <rasd:Caption>1 virtual CPU(s)</rasd:Caption>
        <rasd:InstanceID>1</rasd:InstanceID>
        <rasd:ResourceType>3</rasd:ResourceType>
        <rasd:VirtualQuantity>1</rasd:VirtualQuantity>
      </Item>
      <Item>
        <rasd:AllocationUnits>byte * 2^20</rasd:AllocationUnits>
        <rasd:Description>Memory Size</rasd:Description>
        <rasd:Caption>2048MB of memory</rasd:Caption>
        <rasd:InstanceID>2</rasd:InstanceID>
        <rasd:ResourceType>4</rasd:ResourceType>
        <rasd:VirtualQuantity>2048</rasd:VirtualQuantity>
      </Item>
      <Item>
        <rasd:Address>0</rasd:Address>
        <rasd:Description>SATA Controller</rasd:Description>
        <rasd:Caption>sataController0</rasd:Caption>
        <rasd:InstanceID>3</rasd:InstanceID>
        <rasd:ResourceSubType>AHCI</rasd:ResourceSubType>
        <rasd:ResourceType>20</rasd:ResourceType>
      </Item>
      <Item ovf:required="false">
        <rasd:Address>0</rasd:Address>
        <rasd:Description>USB Controller (EHCI)</rasd:Description>
        <rasd:Caption>usb</rasd:Caption>
        <rasd:InstanceID>4</rasd:InstanceID>
        <rasd:ResourceSubType>vmware.usb.ehci</rasd:ResourceSubType>
        <rasd:ResourceType>23</rasd:ResourceType>
        <vmw:Config ovf:required="false" vmw:key="ehciEnabled" vmw:value="true"/>
      </Item>
      <Item>
        <rasd:Address>0</rasd:Address>
        <rasd:Description>SCSI Controller</rasd:Description>
        <rasd:Caption>scsiController0</rasd:Caption>
        <rasd:InstanceID>5</rasd:InstanceID>
        <rasd:ResourceSubType>lsilogic</rasd:ResourceSubType>
        <rasd:ResourceType>6</rasd:ResourceType>
      </Item>
      <Item>
        <rasd:AddressOnParent>0</rasd:AddressOnParent>
        <rasd:Caption>disk0</rasd:Caption>
        <rasd:HostResource>ovf:/disk/vmdisk1</rasd:HostResource>
        <rasd:InstanceID>6</rasd:InstanceID>
        <rasd:Parent>5</rasd:Parent>
        <rasd:ResourceType>17</rasd:ResourceType>
      </Item>
      <Item>
        <rasd:AddressOnParent>2</rasd:AddressOnParent>
        <rasd:AutomaticAllocation>true</rasd:AutomaticAllocation>
        <rasd:Connection>bridged</rasd:Connection>
        <rasd:Description>PCNet32 ethernet adapter on &quot;bridged&quot;</rasd:Description>
        <rasd:Caption>ethernet0</rasd:Caption>
        <rasd:InstanceID>7</rasd:InstanceID>
        <rasd:ResourceSubType>PCNet32</rasd:ResourceSubType>
        <rasd:ResourceType>10</rasd:ResourceType>
        <vmw:Config ovf:required="false" vmw:key="wakeOnLanEnabled" vmw:value="false"/>
      </Item>
      <Item ovf:required="false">
        <rasd:AutomaticAllocation>false</rasd:AutomaticAllocation>
        <rasd:Caption>sound</rasd:Caption>
        <rasd:InstanceID>8</rasd:InstanceID>
        <rasd:ResourceSubType>vmware.soundcard.ensoniq1371</rasd:ResourceSubType>
        <rasd:ResourceType>1</rasd:ResourceType>
      </Item>
      <Item ovf:required="false">
        <rasd:AutomaticAllocation>false</rasd:AutomaticAllocation>
        <rasd:Caption>video</rasd:Caption>
        <rasd:InstanceID>9</rasd:InstanceID>
        <rasd:ResourceType>24</rasd:ResourceType>
        <vmw:Config ovf:required="false" vmw:key="enable3DSupport" vmw:value="true"/>
      </Item>
      <Item ovf:required="false">
        <rasd:AutomaticAllocation>false</rasd:AutomaticAllocation>
        <rasd:Caption>vmci</rasd:Caption>
        <rasd:InstanceID>10</rasd:InstanceID>
        <rasd:ResourceSubType>vmware.vmci</rasd:ResourceSubType>
        <rasd:ResourceType>1</rasd:ResourceType>
      </Item>
      <Item ovf:required="false">
        <rasd:AddressOnParent>1</rasd:AddressOnParent>
        <rasd:AutomaticAllocation>false</rasd:AutomaticAllocation>
        <rasd:Caption>cdrom0</rasd:Caption>
        <rasd:InstanceID>11</rasd:InstanceID>
        <rasd:Parent>3</rasd:Parent>
        <rasd:ResourceType>15</rasd:ResourceType>
      </Item>
      <vmw:Config ovf:required="false" vmw:key="cpuHotAddEnabled" vmw:value="true"/>
      <vmw:Config ovf:required="false" vmw:key="memoryHotAddEnabled" vmw:value="true"/>
      <vmw:Config ovf:required="false" vmw:key="powerOpInfo.powerOffType" vmw:value="soft"/>
      <vmw:Config ovf:required="false" vmw:key="powerOpInfo.resetType" vmw:value="soft"/>
      <vmw:Config ovf:required="false" vmw:key="powerOpInfo.suspendType" vmw:value="soft"/>
      <vmw:Config ovf:required="false" vmw:key="tools.afterPowerOn" vmw:value="true"/>
      <vmw:Config ovf:required="false" vmw:key="tools.afterResume" vmw:value="true"/>
      <vmw:Config ovf:required="false" vmw:key="tools.beforeGuestShutdown" vmw:value="true"/>
      <vmw:Config ovf:required="false" vmw:key="tools.beforeGuestStandby" vmw:value="true"/>
      <vmw:Config ovf:required="false" vmw:key="tools.syncTimeWithHost" vmw:value="false"/>
    </VirtualHardwareSection>
  </VirtualSystem>
</Envelope>```
````

Comment: Why bother with the OVF file if you can just create a VM with the disk from scratch?

Comment: @DanielB It is because the disk is required for my Autonomous Vehicles class, and it is the disk that is required to be setup with the VM.

Comment: Yes. The disk is required. The OVF is not. Just create an empty Ubuntu VM with 1 vCPU, 2 GB RAM, attach the disk and you should be good to go.

Comment: @DanielB That worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A VM typically consists of at least two parts: The VM definition (vCPU count, RAM amount, network adapters, ...) and a virtual disk. In your case, the VM definition is in Open Virtualization Format and the virtual disk is a dynamically-expanding VMware Virtual Disk (VMDK). VMDK is (also) an open-source format.

You appear to have some problems importing the OVF file directly, but that’s not necessary! As you can see from looking at the file, it has human-readable descriptions on most elements. From this, we can recreate the VM manually and then attach the disk (VirtualBox supports the VMDK format).

The VM is defined as follows:

- Ubuntu Guest OS (from the VM name we can deduce it’s 32-bit Ubuntu)
- 1 vCPU
- 2 GiB RAM
- Virtual SATA controller (AHCI)
- Virtual USB EHCI (USB 2.0) controller
- Virtual SCSI controller (LSI Logic)
- Virtual Disk (attached to SCSI controller)
- Virtual PCNet32 network adapter (Bridged to physical network)
- Virtual AC97 (Ensoniq 1371) sound card
- Virtual graphics adapter with 3D acceleration enabled
- VMCI host-guest communication interface (VMware-specific, not available on VirtualBox)
- Virtual optical drive (attached to SATA controller)

Because this is an Ubuntu system, an exact recreation of all resources is not really required. Instead, you can focus on some key points:

- 1 vCPU
- 2+ GiB RAM
- Virtual Disk attached to SCSI or SATA (so it is `sda`)

Everything else is probably not really required. If you have 3D visualizations, enabling 3D (somewhat experimental in VirtualBox) may be beneficial. They require the VirtualBox Guest Additions to be installed.